# How to iterate client.get from Twitter API using node.js and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, express, twitter

I'm building an app to download specific number of tweets. I'm using `node.js` and `express()` in server.js.

I created a rout `app.get('/api/tweets'...)` to save data from Twitter API. My code works well if I return 200 tweets. However, if I want more than 300 or so, `res.send(data)` only returns a few.

I created my code based on my code written in python, which returns all tweets allowed by Twitter API (3,200):

```
allTweets = []
statuses = t.statuses.user_timeline(screen_name = 'user', count=100, include_rts=False) 
allTweets.extend(statuses)
oldest = allTweets[-1]['id'] - 1

while len(statuses) > 0:
    statuses = t.statuses.user_timeline(screen_name = 'user', count=100, max_id=oldest, include_rts=False)
    allTweets.extend(statuses)
    oldest = allTweets[-1]['id'] - 1
```

Based on this lines, I wrote in `JavaScript` this code in server.js:

```
app.get('/api/tweets', function (req, res) {
    var standardCount = 200;
    var params = {
        screen_name: 'user',
        count: standardCount,
        include_rts: false
    };
    var statuses = client.get('statuses/user_timeline', params, function getTweets(error, data) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
        var tweets = data;
        var oldest = parseInt((tweets.slice(-1)[0].id_str) - 1);

        // This attempt works fine using if
        if (0 < data.length) {
            params = {
                screen_name: 'user',
                count: standardCount,
                max_id: oldest,
                include_rts: false
            }
            client.get('statuses/user_timeline', params, function getTweets(error, data) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
                tweets = tweets.concat(data);
                oldest = parseInt((tweets.slice(-1)[0].id_str) - 1);
                return res.send(tweets.slice(0, 500)));
            });
        }
    });
});
```

My first attempt was `while (0 < data.length)`, but it didn't return nothing. I changed it for `if (0 < data.length)`, however it returns only a few tweets. I tried:

```
do {
   // download tweets
}
while (0 < data.length)
```

...with not success.

What is the best way to iterate `client.get` using Twitter API to download more than 200 tweets?

Comment: I don't see where you can update `standardCount` to be anything other than 200.

Comment: @ExplosionPills `count` parameter in `client.get(statuses/user_timeline)` specifies the number of Tweets to try and retrieve, up to a maximum of 200 per distinct request.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want a recursive function to obtain your dataset:

```
function obtainTweets (params, number, offsetId, dataset, callback) {
  dataset = dataset || []
  if (number < 0) return callback(null, dataset)
  // ... update params
  return client.get('...', params, (error, data) => {
    if (error) return callback(error)
    // .. logic to get new offsetId
    dataset = dataset.concat(data)
    return obtainTweets(params, number-200, offsetId, dataset, callback)
  })
}
```

Here we defined a method `obtainTweets` that takes `params` object, the `number` of tweets you would like to obtain, `offsetId` should it exist, the current `dataset` and a `callback` to allow for returning your dataset once the iterations completed.

Each time an iteration is completed we subtract the max `200` from the number given until we reach `0` and `callback` is invoked unless an error occurs.

It would be used like so:

```
obtainTweets({ user: 'some_user' }, 600, null, null, (error, data) => {
   console.log(error, data)
})
```

Comment: I've shortened and removed the promises example, I would urge you to look into promises as they can prevent you from running into a stack overflow from large numbers of tweets you would like to fetch, you can also use `nextTick` however that's more of a hack than a solution.

Comment: Thnaks. I will check your recommendation. I need to implement your answer. Best.